# Remove shortcode based on its attribute

Tags: wordpress, attr, shortcode

What if I want to prevent a shortcode from running (ideally removing it) based on a specific attribute?

For example, I have 3 toggles on a post: [toggle title="yes"] [toggle title="maybe"] [toggle title="no"], and I need to prevent [toggle title="no"] from showing. More than that, I need to completely remove toggles with "no" as a title attribute, but without affecting the other toggles.

I know I can use an IF statement like this:

```
if ( $atts ['title'] == "no" ) { return " "; }
```

But doing so is not good, cause the others toggles would not be executed.

Would somebody help me achieving that?

Comment: Would [else if](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) help?

Comment: can you post your current code? Because you can have an else that returns the value you desire when title isn't "no"

Comment: Hey Man, Thanks! It was a typo... It really works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it was my mistake. Simply set an ELSE statement and the others toggle shortcodes will be executed.

Thanks.